# What's the English word for a short-lived feeling of euphoria?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

This is a bit hard to put in words.

Let's say you're just coming out of a theater after watching a movie. You're thinking about the movie you just watched. You're feeling that the movie was the greatest movie you ever saw (that you'll give it 10 out of 10).

Some time passes, say a couple of days, and you're again thinking about it. This time, however, you're feeling that the movie was just okay, it wasn't as great as you thought two days before (that you'll give it 7 out of 10).

My question is, what do you call what you were feeling earlier (or how do you put it in words)?

Comment: You probably mean "a short-lived" feeling of greatness. And the question then answers itself.

Comment: `exhilaration` comes to mind, especially since you mention euphoria :)

Comment: You could say it was "Orgasmic."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about *infatuation*? It describes an intense but short-lived passion or admiration for someone or something. I felt exactly like this about the movie *Her* recently.

Answer (score 2):

> Formal: [**thrill**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thrill) *- a wave or nervous tremor of emotion or sensation*
>
> Informal: [**buzz**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/buzz?q=buzz) *- a feeling of excitement or euphoria; a thrill*

In both cases, the feeling is invariably relatively short-lived.

Answer (score 2):

**Rush** or **buzz** would be fine in an informal context

"I got such a rush (of excitement) thinking back on the movie"

Comment: It would be better to include an authoritative reference to the definition that you have in mind. E.g., Rush:  A sudden, **brief** exhilaration. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rush (10b)

Comment: ‘Rush’ was exactly the word I was going to suggest, too. +1.

Answer (score 1):

If that feeling is accompanied with a heightened connection with the artfulness of the film, you could call it an:

> **epiphanic moment**

This is, to paraphrase a handbook on literary terms, when sudden illumination and rational realization converge.

The epiphanic moment, compared with the feelings of euphoria or excitement, isn't prolonged and by definition fades into a different mode of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answered your own question.  Euphoria implies a short-lived feeling; thus, euphoria is the word for which you are looking.  On a more "base" or slang-ish level, I think "high" and "buzz" also work.

Answer (score 1):

It has several meanings which might cloud the issue, but a word that has a definition that seems to fit is *fancy*. Its [Google definition](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=fancy+meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) currently provides this definition for the use of *fancy* as a noun:

> a feeling of liking or attraction, typically one that is superficial or transient.

And on [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fancy) *fancy* has ties with capriciousness, transience, irrationality and whimsy. In the movie example, if the subject decides he was completely off base in his original assessment, the subject may have indulged in a [*flight of fancy*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/flight+of+fancy).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer specifically to the phenomena as it relates to entertainment, consider the related terms [**fridge logic**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FridgeLogic) and **icebox scene,** which refer to the way that things you previously found entertaining tend to evaporate when you later muse over them while rummaging through the fridge/icebox.

Comment: Warning: tvtropes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no perfect word here as far as I'm concerned, but the following all have some connotations of transience of the feeling.

- elation
- glee
- jubilation
- euphoria (!)